# Is there a way to just install part of visual studio 2013 to support msbuild and if yes which packages I need

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, package

I'm setting up a build server and I'm trying to install the minimum I can. I don't want to install all the visual studio 2013 express, How I can do that? also I'm assuming I need the vs2013 command line to support msbuild correct?

Thanks
Jp

Comment: Having *just* msbuild doesn't seem useful: don't you need the compiler, standard library etc as well?

Answer (score 0):

> If you don't have Visual Studio installed on your computer, you can
>   use [Build Tools 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760) to build managed applications. The Visual Basic
>   and C# compilers are also included in this download. (In earlier
>   versions, these tools were included in the stand-alone .NET
>   Framework.)

Similarly, [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) and 2015 [Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools).